# How long did it take to get to the Midway Station?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, stargate-atlantis

After harvesting a bunch of Pegasus stargates, McKay & Co. daisy-chains them end-to-end until they end up halfway between the Pegasus & Milky Way galaxies where they build the Midway Station. Then the same happens on the other half of the trip to the SGC with harvested Milky Way stargates, drastically reducing the time to get from Atlantis to the SGC vs. the long trip on the Deadalus at FTL speeds.

How long did it take to get to Midway from Atlantis via the Stargates? I guess it come down to how long the transit time is between two simple stargates?

Answer (score 3):

From [the Stargate Wiki page about the bridge](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/McKay/Carter_Intergalactic_Gate_Bridge):

> Travel time using the bridge is approximately 30 minutes, a drastic reduction from the weeks-long journey required via ship.

and

> a space station has been constructed at the midpoint between the two galaxies

So travel time to the station, from either end, would be around 15 minutes by stargate.

Comment: Travel from either end could be considerably shorter than 15 minutes, assuming that anyone travelling through would probably require at least a cursory medical exam, if not a day or two of quanantine.

Comment: @Xantec Mandatory 24-hour quarantine ([Teal'c and Ronon](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Midway_(episode)) should draw up some memories...)

Comment: Where is the wiki drawing this information from?